# How to handle specific values in a very specific way in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
     TIMESTAMP              TAIR
0    2011-06-01 00:00:00    24.3
1    2011-06-01 00:05:00    24.5
2    2011-06-01 00:10:00    24.2
3    2011-06-01 00:15:00    24.1
4    2011-06-01 00:20:00    24.2
5    2011-06-01 00:25:00    -999
6    2011-06-01 00:30:00    15.1
7    2011-06-01 00:35:00    -999
8    2011-06-01 00:40:00    13.9
9    2011-06-01 00:45:00    13.7
```

I need to handle the missing values (anything less than -990) by replacing it with the preceding value. So, if I do this correctly, the new dataframe would look like this:

```
     TIMESTAMP              TEMP
0    2011-06-01 00:00:00    24.3
1    2011-06-01 00:05:00    24.5
2    2011-06-01 00:10:00    24.2
3    2011-06-01 00:15:00    24.1
4    2011-06-01 00:20:00    24.2
5    2011-06-01 00:25:00    24.2
6    2011-06-01 00:30:00    15.1
7    2011-06-01 00:35:00    15.1
8    2011-06-01 00:40:00    13.9
9    2011-06-01 00:45:00    13.7
```

The timestamp is datetime datatype.

How I am doing this now is with a for loop like so:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['TAIR'] < -990:
        data.loc[index, 'TAIR'] = data.loc[index-1, 'TAIR']
```

Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: You should remove the second half of your question and ask a new question.  Try to avoid asking multiple separate questions in a single question

Comment: @user3483203 Watch out for the incoming noob!!!! (Edited second question as per suggestion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using `mask` and `ffill`:

```
df.assign(TAIR=df.TAIR.mask(df.TAIR.le(-999)).ffill())
```

```
             TIMESTAMP  TAIR
0  2011-06-01 00:00:00  24.3
1  2011-06-01 00:05:00  24.5
2  2011-06-01 00:10:00  24.2
3  2011-06-01 00:15:00  24.1
4  2011-06-01 00:20:00  24.2
5  2011-06-01 00:25:00  24.2
6  2011-06-01 00:30:00  15.1
7  2011-06-01 00:35:00  15.1
8  2011-06-01 00:40:00  13.9
9  2011-06-01 00:45:00  13.7
```

Comment: I approve of this answer 

Comment: @user3483203 Brilliant!

Comment: @AkshayGaur happy to help, remember that both of these one liners *do not* modify the dataframe in place, but instead return an updated copy.  If you need to modify the original dataframe you can just replace `df.assign` with `df['Tair'] = ` etc..

Comment: @user3483203 The np.where one doesn't work though. My df has -999 from idx 30636 thru 30656 and performing `df = df.assign(TAIR=np.where(df.TAIR.le(-990), df.TAIR.shift(), df.TAIR))` doesn't actually change the values when I confirm with df[30630:30660].

Comment: Ah, you are correct, if there are multiple "bad" values in a row, it is not guaranteed that it will work.  Good catch! I removed it from the answer

Comment: you are looking for `df.update(df.TAIR.where(df.TAIR>-999).ffill())`

Comment: @Onyambu the second one won't work if there are multiple bad values in a row

Answer (score 2):

Replace by `np.nan` and use `ffill()`

```
df.loc[df.TAIR <= -990, 'TAIR'] = np.nan
df.ffill()
```

Comment: This is a great answer too. I guess I liked the one-liner from by user3483203 better.

Comment: @AkshayGaur Glad to help ;) yea definitely, using `mask` was a great catch :) I also upvoted that answer